# Bulk category update is not updating

Tags: categories, bulk

I am using wordpress 3.1. and I have to reorganize categorize my posts. For this purpose, I am willing to remove some categories. Therefore, after login to admin section of my blog, I go to post > posts > I select the articles I want to edit > I select edit option from "Bulk Action" select box > I select new categories and put some tags as well. But it adds tags only. It doesn't remove previously assigned categories.

Please let me know if there is any plugin to do the same work. Or some other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bulk category update (wordpress inclusive) just for adding more categories or to remove a category which is among all selected posts.

Answer (score 1):

I found this plugin: [batch categories plugin](http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2007/01/batch-categories-wordpress-plugin-bulk-edit-your-categories/). I don't know anything about it, but it looks like it meets your needs